# Code Coverage Data Generation Failed for Swift 3.0

Tags: xcode7, xctest, swift3

I am testing a library project; the tests passed with this error message:

```
Aggregation tool
'/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/llvm-profdata'
failed with exit code 1
```

I am not using the default toolchain (Swift 2.2) but the latest snapshot.
I switched my toolchain in Xcode preference and it builds and runs the
tests successfully; it just does not generate code coverage data. I
noticed that the [`llvm-profdata`](http://llvm.org/docs/CommandGuide/llvm-profdata.html) belongs to the default
toolchain, but I did not find any `llvm-profdata` in the corresponding
folder of the Swift 3.0 toolchain.

Environment:

- OS X 10.11.5 (latest)
- Xcode 7.3.1 (latest)
- Swift June 6, 2016: LLVM cb08d1dbbd, Clang 383859a9c4, Swift
  9e8266aaeb (latest)

I am not familiar with the Swift toolchain; how can I get more
information about why `llvm-profdata` failed, possibly with Xcode command
line tools? Or is this a bug in the current version of Swift?

Note:

- Xcode gives me the error only for Swift 3.0; I manually checked

  ```
  Build/Intermediates/CodeCoverage/Coverage.profdata
  ```

  in build folder with `llvm-profdata show`, and it is empty only when
  I compile with Swift 3.

Comment: It is a known missing feature in the toolchain. There is currently a todo on master, and an open pull request awaiting review that claims to resolve the issue.

Comment: @DavidSkrundz Great to know this. Thank you! Do you happen to know where are the pull request and TODO? I searched on [GitHub](https://github.com/apple/swift/pulls) and [bug tracker](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR) but did not find anything mentioning this feature.

Comment: Here is the pull request. https://github.com/apple/swift-package-manager/pull/184

Comment: Wow, I searched in wrong repository. Thanks!

Comment: @DavidSkrundz Do you like to add that as an independent answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue in the swift package manager. There is currently an open pull request which can be found at: https://github.com/apple/swift-package-manager/pull/184

Edit: It has been pulled in, and is available in Xcode 8